# Why 0.1 * 3 != 0.3

Tags: math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

I was reading [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know) question and found this in the comments (on The Communist Duck's answer). After making sure that I'd not lost my mind I find myself curious.

So why is 0.1 * 3 != 0.3 ?

(note, the question was regarding game development and which fields of math a game developer should be familiar with)

Comment: multiple duplicates, search for floating point in SO questions

Answer (score 6):

Ther reason is that only numbers that are powers of 2 can be represented precisely with a simple binary representation.

The individual digits of a binary number are different powers of 2 and any number is thus a sum of different powers of 2.

`0.1` does not correspond to a power of 2 and can not be summed up from different powers of 2. Thus it can be represented only with a certain error. You can find a more elaborate explanation and examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary)

If you need precise numbers, you are mostly bound to use integers. I am not sure about other languages, but in java there are several classes designed to overcome exactly this issue for applications where precision is essential,like in financial computations. Most prominent are [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is due to [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), which is the way computers store floating point numbers.

With this representation, 0.1 cannot be even represented exactly by a 96bit float. Neither can 0.3 for that matter, but if the latter were, as 0.1 cannot be represented exactly, it means that multiplying it by 3 would not yield 0.3 exactly.