# Rounding off issue in java

Tags: java

I am using `math.round()` to round off.

this is the code:

```
double value=0.145
Math.round( value* 100.0) / 100.0;
```

My expectation is it should return `0.15` but it is returning `0.14`.

Also, if the value is `0.055`, then it is returning `0.05` instead of `0.06`
I have already gone through the link [round up to 2 decimal places in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java)
Please tell me specific that why this is happening?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and 
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)

Comment: Check out what `value*100` is before rounding: http://ideone.com/oNJ9h9

Answer (score 0):

If you would print `value * 100.0`, you would find that this is not actually 14.5 as you would expect, but it's close to 14.499999999999998 (on my jdk1.8.0_181). As you can see, it would give you 0.14 as final result.

Why it happened, this is how floating point arithmetic is supposed to work. When you have a value that cannot be properly represented by binary system, you will face this problem. I am giving links to answers that gives good information why it happens.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089026/841221

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8604224/841221

**EDIT : Update 1**
As matt suggested, it's actually `0.145` which cannot be represented by binary properly. As per IEEE754 Double Precision 64-Bit representation, it's actually is 1.44999999999999990007992778374E-1 which is not exactly 0.145.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, 14.5 can be exactly represented, but 0.145 cannot. So the first `value` is less than 0.145.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @matt. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Math.ceil(0.145)` to get your desired result `0.15`.